# Android SDK Live-Camera (Videocall) forwarding to server

Tags: android, video-streaming, web-development-server

I use an app for video calls (not my own) (Android) and would now like to **forward** the incoming video stream to my server, through which other people can then watch.

My current idea is to develop an Android App (Webapp or native?), which monitors the camera-stream as background-app, takes the stream and forwards it to my nodejs-server.

Questions:
How can I forward the received video stream ?
Is it even possible ?
Which technologies, SDKs, libraries are available for this purpose?
Does it also work with Web-Technologies / Frameworks like Cordova ?

Maybe someone can give me a hint to the right direction

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use scenarios, whether a **Live Streaming** or **Video Chat**, the solution is huge different, please check link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401471/17679565).

Beside the protocols, the Cluster or CDN service is also very important, choose a solution that CDN is support, unless you only provide service to a small group of people.