# how to use the ant media server with flutter using the Rest API

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webrtc, rtmp

I want to create a stream app like TIKTOK using flutter ,
I am using the ant media server and I am using the REST API to create room
and to create stream and it is working .
the problem is that I do not  know what to do next ?
do I have to create a signaling using the stuns ? if it is yes , how I can do that ?
and is the any library that can plays the stream like the OBS Studio and the VLC ?
do I have to use the Web Sockets ?
!! please help !!

Comment: are you successfully done the streaming part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about `Live Streaming` and `Video Chat`, which are both very important but different video platforms and use scenarios, and their architecture is totally different.

I think `TIKTOK` is an mobile app with:

- Most of it is `VoD` file and social connections.
- Some part is `Live Streaming`, like twitch.tv or YouTube live streaming.
- Few of `Video Chat` ability, only when two user are talking in a RTC room.

For `VoD`, it's something like HTTP(S) files, deliver by CDN or Nginx if you want to build it.

About the `Live Streaming` and `Video Chat`, please read detail from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401471/17679565).

Comment: bro, thank you so much . know I understand everything ♥.